# Does the word party in the “Boston tea party” mean a literal party or a political party?

Tags: united-states, parties, political-system

Did the term party already represent a political meaning at that time as a group of people, or was it just used as a celebration term?

Comment: This might be an interesting question to ask on [history.se] to see how and why this name came to be, but there isn’t a deeper political meaning

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can easily be looked up [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Tea_Party).

Answer (score 12):

A '[tea party](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tea-party)' is a social gathering, usually in the afternoon, at which tea and light refreshments are served. It is a calm and somewhat formal affair, and in the USA, it is commonly associated with the British.

In the early USA, self-effacing humor was a large part of American identity. For example, [Yankee Doodle](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/65651/why-did-yankee-doodle-call-feather-macaroni) was originally sung by British soldiers in mockery of American yokels who thought themselves fancy, and Americans took the song as their own, priding themselves on their 'rustic' nature.

It wasn't until 1826 that the 'destruction of the tea' was branded the Boston Tea Party. This was in a period when all kinds of wry 'Americanisms' were coined, like 'Boston cream pie' (actually a cake filled with custard),'Arizona strawberries' (beans), Cape Cod turkey (baked salt-cod), Albany beef (sturgeon eggs before it became trendy), Norfolk capon (red herring), Alaska turkey (salmon), Texas turkey (armadillo), and many, many more.

So the phrase 'Boston Tea Party' was less about a political party or raiding party, and more a joke about how a bunch of commonfolk Bostonians had their afternoon tea: by destroying British property.

Answer (score 6):

[This article](http://bostonreview.net/alfred-f-young-boston-tea-party) explains:

> **At the time, the event that took place in Boston on the night of December 16, 1773 was not called the “Tea Party.”** For more than 50 years, if it was mentioned at all in print, it was usually as “the destruction of the tea.” Bostonians never celebrated it as they did their triumphs over other British measures. Patriot leaders cited the Indian disguises worn by some in the boarding parties in order to deny responsibility for the affair and claim it was the work of outsiders.

I'm not sure exactly how the term "Boston Tea Party" caught on, but I always took the word "party" in the sense of "raiding party", which [Wiktionary defines](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raiding_party) as a "**group of people who band together to make a raid or foray.**" The historical event originally known as "the destruction of the tea" was neither a celebration nor an organized political party.

Answer (score -2):

We, in the USSR were taught of it as "бостонское чаепитие", that is "Boston tea-drinking". In other words, a party in the meaning of spending time together.

Years later I encountered the term "tea party" in the Internet and thought it meant some right-wing political movement in the US. Only this question linked these two things for me.